# ArrayAccess in Ruby

Tags: php, arrays, ruby, hash

PHP has an interface you can implement in a class called `ArrayAccess` with methods such as `offsetGet`, `offsetSet`, etc. which allow a class to be referenced in with array notation, but the code can determine how to handle the keys and values in the array (or hash). One benefit of this is to pass in dot-notation as a key and it is converted into a nested hash. Another advantage is that you can have `offsetGet` always return a default value rather than throwing notices if you don't check if the key is actually set or not first.

Is there any functionality like this in Ruby? I'd really like to make a utility class, like a `ParameterBag`, to handle config values, dot-notated keys, etc.

Comment: Ruby has [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html) for this purpose, but I would suggest you not to reinvent a wheel and take a look at brilliant [`Hashie::Mash`](https://github.com/intridea/hashie#mash).

Comment: If you want to use an object like `myObject = MyClass.new(); myObject[0] = 1` you just have to overload the '[]' operator for MyClass: `def [](key) ... end` and  `def []=(key, value) ... end`